# Continuous Deployment with TeamCity 2018 In Windows 10

Tags: teamcity, continuous-deployment

I want to setup **Continuous Deployment** in Teamcity 2018 without any third party software.
When I want to deploy, It should copy my code to some other folder where my site is published/hosted.

how can I do it?
This is how my screen is looking !

[image: Build Configuration]

Build screen is below

[image: Home]

I found no support which explains step by step.

Comment: it depends on your environment.. is it linux, windows, or some static hosting in the cloud...

Comment: @daggett - It is windows.

Comment: for windows the simplest without using extra software - powershell. just search how to put file on remote computer with powershell

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to 
https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD10/Continuous+Integration+with+TeamCity

Also, the path purely depends upon your environment. I would recommend to use windows as I am very much comfortable with it and rest depends upon what environment you have.

Comment: Please ready my question again. I am asking for Continuous Deployment, not continuous Integration.